# Regex for matching token wrapped in %

Tags: php, regex

I have user-entered text with potentially mistyped "tokens" I'm trying to find **using PHP**.

A valid "token" is any number of word characters wrapped in percent signs - so `%blah%` `%blah_moreblah%`.  Basically I'm looking for tokens where the user may have forgotten to put a leading or trailing '%'.  I'm also looking for tokens in the valid format - as at this point in my code, all replaceable tokens have already been replaced.

So, the 3 situations I'm looking for are (to borrow regex syntax): `%\w+`, `%\w+%`, or `\w+%`.

In English, what I'm looking for is, "a string that starts with a % and/or ends with a % and contains only word characters'

The regex I have this far is: `(%*\w+%*)`, but you'll notice it matches every single word.  I'm stuck on making a match *require* at least a leading or a trailing %.

**Edit**: Initially I tried to have all 3 situations found with their own regex.  However, I was finding that the regex for finding tokens in the first situation would also find tokens in the second situation, just without the trailing %.  For example, `/(%\w+)/`, when checked against `%before %both%`, would match `%before` and `%both`.

Comment: Why not use alternation [`%\w+\b(?!%)|(?<!%)\b\w+%`](https://regex101.com/r/gP3nT2/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match tokens enclosed with `%`, or having `%` on either side, use

```
(?=\w*%)%*\w+%*
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH0uO9/1).

This is *your* pattern that I added a positive lookahead to. The `(?=\w*%)` restricts to only such matches where a `%` appears after a zero or more occurrences of word characters.

Note also that `%*` will match *zero or more* percent signs, it may match `%%%word%%`. If it is not what you need, and if you need to match 1 or 0 `%`s, just replace the `*` with `?` quantifier.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, that regex doesn't match my second requirement, which is a word that has both a leading and trailing %.  I have updated my question a little bit to make it clearer, as I can see how you made the assumption of only wanting a leading or a trailing %, but not both.

Comment: Ok, so both sides, or just one. Use a lookahead: [`(?=\w*%)%*\w+%*`](https://regex101.com/r/hH0uO9/1)

Comment: I figured a lookahead/lookbehind was what I wanted, but my Regex Fu is not that advanced.  Would you mind making the lookahead regex an official answer and I'll accept it?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Done. [**Lookarounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are not that difficult by themselves. As for me, it is more difficult to work with nested groupings.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$input_lines = "Hello this is a %string% with %some_words in it just for demo% purposes.";

preg_match_all("/\s[\w_\-]+%\.?|%[\w_\-]+(%|\s|\.)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

**That will output this:**

```
array(
    0   =>  %string%
    1   =>  %some_words 
    2   =>   demo%
)
```

*Note that this will catch the valid cases, as well as the typos you are looking for.*